# RDFLib + JSON-LD + Named Graphs: how to override graph name when using @graph?

Tags: python, semantic-web, json-ld, rdflib

### Disposition

Full illustrative code is available at this [Gist](https://gist.github.com/anatoly-scherbakov/e1c75db34a262f7aa107d82399c50c52).

Imagine we're describing a blog article in a JSON-LD document. In addition to a few properties of the article itself (its type and label), we want to add some semantic data for the purposes of that article. In this example, we define a `Robot` class and a `Rover` as its subclass, using `@graph` keyword.

```json
{
    "@context": {
        "schema": "https://schema.org/",
        "blog": "https://blog.me/",
        "ex": "https://example.org/",
        "rdfs": "http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#"
    },
    "@id": "blog:JSONLD-and-named-graphs",
    "@type": "schema:blogPost",
    "rdfs:label": "JSON-LD and Named Graphs",
    "@graph": [
        {
            "@id": "ex:Robot",
            "@type": "rdfs:Class"
        },
        {
            "@id": "ex:Rover",
            "rdfs:subClassOf": {
                "@id": "ex:Robot"
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

Using Python `rdflib`, we want to import all of this into a named graph designated as https://myblog.net/rdf/ — like this:

```py
    ...
    graph = ConjunctiveGraph()

    serialized_document = json.dumps(JSONLD_DOCUMENT)

    graph.parse(
        data=serialized_document,
        format='json-ld',
        # All the semantic data about my blog is stored in a particular
        # named graph.
        publicID='https://myblog.net/rdf/',
    )
```

### Expected Result

All the data should be imported under named graph https://myblog.net/rdf/ based on the `publicID` argument.

### Actual Result

In fact, we get two named graphs in our RDF dataset:

- https://myblog.net/rdf/ which contains data about the article itself (its id, type and label),
- and https://blog.me/JSONLD-and-named-graphs graph which contains everything from `@graph` section.

This is not a bug, this is what JSON-LD semantics [prescribes](https://www.w3.org/TR/json-ld/#named-graphs). `{"@id": "badoom", "@graph": {...}}` means we've described a named `@graph` and provided its name as `@id`.

### Question

Can we somehow *override* JSON-LD semantics and force RDFLib to import the whole of the input data into named graph specified by `publicID` argument?

Versions of the software:

```
Python 3.8.1
rdflib==5.0.0
rdflib-jsonld==0.5.0
PyLD==2.0.3
```

Answer (score 1):

It appears the appropriate tool for this job is `@included` keyword instead of `@graph`. See [the JSON-LD 1.1 spec](https://www.w3.org/TR/json-ld/#included-blocks). That worked for me.

(**P. S.** I had to flatten the document before it worked with RDFLib; see [the GitHub issue](https://github.com/RDFLib/rdflib-jsonld/issues/98).)